# i18n for Spring Boot web application - frontend/backend

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, spring-boot

I would have a question concerning i18n for a Spring boot web application.
In the backend I read the properties files like this:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:public/app/lang/i18n/backend/messages");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
    return messageSource;
}
```

In frontend I read the lang-x like this:

```
function configure($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        files: [{
            prefix: 'app/lang/i18n/lang-',
            suffix: '.json'
        }]
    });
```

My question now would be if there is a possibility to consolidate this two i18n technologies at the one side for frontend and on the other side for backend.
Thanks a lot!

[image: i18n for backend and frontend]

Comment: If you're doing the i18n in the angular frontend, you shouldn't need to do it on the server, except maybe for things that can't be done on the frontend, like generate downloadable files or things like that. But then the properties would be different. If you really need to share properties,  would leave them in the JSON files and read and parse the JSON files at startup in the backend.